# Do Not Capitalize Each Word In Profile Menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Each item in the [user profile edit menu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) is capitalized:

> [image: enSO]

Probably it's normal for English, but not good for other languages like Russian:

> [image: ruSO]

Link to your profile for Stack Overflow in Russian [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current).

Is it possible to allow translators to decide which letter case should be used in each separate case?

Possibly related to [this issue](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3708/176217) and should be fixed by modifying CSS.

Comment: Theyshouldinsteadseparateallwordswithhandclappingemoji

Comment: @Won't emoji must die! At least on SE. P.S. I'm glad to see your funny comment on my post again :)

Comment: I't pretty standard in English to do this for titles, so I don't think they're going to change it for the English sites.

Comment: It's indeed pretty standard in English, but it s***s. (Why? Because it harms readability.) So if this could be propagated to the English sites as well, I'd be grateful. At the very least, it would be consistent with the capitalization of (most) questions on all sites in the network.

Comment: @Glorfindel Headings are not question titles... I disagree with your assertion that they should be in sentence case when they're *not* sentences. I don't understand why "Ask question" is more readable than "Ask Question". The title of this question is annoying and difficult to read but the headings are only two or three words at most. I'm honestly more perturbed that it's not "Ask **a** Question".

Comment: @Catija https://medium.com/@jsaito/making-a-case-for-letter-case-19d09f653c98 in the Apple vs. Google debate, this is one of the very few cases where I agree with Google. Actually, the optimal readability seems to be somewhere in the middle; if you capitalize all nouns, like German does, you come close. But that's a discussion for another place (and time?), we're going off-topic and it's probably my fault.

Comment: Not sure why this got a site-specific close vote. Russian SO isn't the only localized site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This Is Fixed In The Next Build. I Have Also Applied The Fix On [Rus.Se](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) As Well As [Es.So](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). On [Pt.So](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) I Have Left It As Is, Because A [Trustworthy Person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/175506/gabe?tab=profile) Has Assured Me That Speaking Like This Is A Thing In Portuguese.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Большое От Всего Русскоязычного Сообщества! Don't forget Ja.SO :)

Comment: My understanding is that there is no casing in Japanese, so that wouldn't really be an issue, right?

Comment: It's a joke about Ja.

Comment: Because this fix should not be applied to beta sites :-D

Comment: How long need to wait for a new build? It's still old after 15 minutes.

Comment: We deploy multiple times a day, but not for every single fix :)

Comment: Sometimes I see a bunch of builds (according to rev#) within a ~10 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, that usually happens when someone broke something and needs to rollback and/or fix :)

Comment: It's happening too often :) Will wait for build before accepting.

Comment: @alexolut where can I see the build number as well?

Comment: @NVZ at the bottom of every page. Right angle.

Comment: @alexolut It's deployed now.

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have capitalized letters on rus.stackexchange.com. Could you please fix it? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312035/379531