# Upper case in the interface of profile settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization, russian-stackexchange

I wonder to know that we have different register rules of writing titles in profile settings on [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/232295) and ["Русский язык" site](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/edit/178412). In Russian, it is important not to use capital letters writing every word in a title. So, we should have "Profile **s**ettings", not "Profile Settings". Please fix it.

[image: The wrong way to write titles]

[image: The correct one]

Comment: This should be asked at https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ or https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: @JasonBassford why do you think so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Not Capitalize Each Word In Profile Menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300894/do-not-capitalize-each-word-in-profile-menu)

Comment: @alexolut it is, but, as I see, the ruSO only has non-capitalized letters.

Comment: @Aer according to answer it should be fixed for rus.SE too. Probably regress has failed or not fixed correctly for all affected sites.

Comment: @alexolut so, that’s why I’ve asked this question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This looks fixed now](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current):

> [image: рябета]