# Do Not Capitalize Each Word In Tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Could you please remove the automatic capitalization on tabs (e.g. [Question page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions), [Users page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users)) for localized sites like [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)?

> [image: questions]

> [image: users]

This lies on the translator's shoulders.

Related questions:

- [Do Not Capitalize Each Word In Profile Menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300894)
- [Upper case in the interface of profile settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312035/339911)

Comment: Same for SOes please!

Comment: Is There A Reason Why?

Comment: @Mari-LouA because it's wrong to use capitalized word in the middle of the sentence in Russian. If it's not a abbreviation of course.

Comment: But a sentence needs a subject and a verb, I doubt "Profile Page" or "New Users" can be considered sentences even in English. They're just titles, names of tabs. Names are capitalised...

Comment: @Mari-LouA maybe I should use term "phrase" instead of "sentence" here. But even in Russian phrase capitalized words in the middle look very odd.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Names Are Capitalized Only in English, so automatic capitalization needs to be a per-site (or per-localization language) setting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's an issue on all of the non-English sites. Title case is not used in Spanish, Russian, or Portuguese.

Comment: @Catija Questions/requests/bugs should be self-contained. I was already aware of this issue but it is not common knowledge among native speakers. The OP could at least *explain* the reason for asking; e.g. capitalising nouns in titles is rarely, if ever, done in Russian.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315979/260198 [tag:status-planned]...4 month ago   (¬‿¬ ). And as Catija said, this shouldn't be title case even on English sites.

Comment: @Catija Will SE soon implement title case in Japanese? :) Amazing new linguistical invention by SE!

Comment: Looks like they have fixed it.

Comment: @Suvitruf we now need to fix translations

Comment: @älёxölüt lets do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We used a short term CSS solution to fix the preferred casing of our question filters... which caused some issues down the line with our translations.

These strings were changed in the markup on English, and will be translated down the line with proper translations.

We've published our [grammar and mechanics section on Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/content/grammar-and-mechanics#buttons-and-links), which should help in casing decisions in the future—both in refactors and new views.

Comment: Stacks is open source. You can file a GitHub issue for anything you find by clicking the GitHub logo at the top right of each page or go directly to our repo https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks