# Inconsistency with case in tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tabs

On the most pages text in tabs is capitalized:

- [Home](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

  > [image: home]
- [Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)

  > [image: questions]
- [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

  > [image: tags]
- [Tagged questions when Custom Lists is disabled](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning):

  > [image: ell]
- [Unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

  > [image: unanswered]

But don't for [users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) page:

> [image: users]

Is it intentional, or just oversight after fixing the [related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323190/339911)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tabs on [users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) are Capitalized now:

> [image: Users]

"Info" tab is fixed as well:

> [image]

Comment: It looks like there is still one inconsistency. On the Users page: "New users" tab. The first word in capitalized but the second word (users) is not. However, on the unanswered questions page: "My Tags". Bot words are capitalized. I think the convention used in the users page is correct (only the first word should be capitalized).

Comment: @KodosJohnson I think for American English each capitalized word is more preferred according the following [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323216/339911). Hence, the issue is in “New users”, not in “My Tags”.

Comment: But that post you linked to links to [here](https://stackoverflow.design/content/grammar-and-mechanics#buttons-and-links) and that page says that each word should not be capitalized. Also I remember an SE staff member saying that only the first word should be capitalized. That's why I said that only the first word should be capitalized, even if I personally prefer all words to be capitalized.

Comment: @KodosJohnson you’re probably right. It seems that the time for posting another bug report is come.